# How to get the length of the images folder ruby in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a gifs folder inside the images folder. The gifs folder has a list of gifs

```
app/assets/images/gifs
```

I want to get the length of this gifs folder (how many gifs are in this folder) so that I can randomly render a gif

```
<%= image_tag "thank_you_gifs/#{rand(***gifs.length***)}.gif", width: "370" %>
```

I don't want to hard code the length because gifs are periodically added to the gifs folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Dir.glob(pattern)](https://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/glob/class):

```rb
Dir.glob("app/assets/images/gifs/*").size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Dir.glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to find the list of `gif` files in `app/assets/images/gifs` and then call the `length` method on the list to get the count.

```rb
Dir.glob('*.gif', base: Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/gifs')).length
```